Matching only types for a list of items
I created this project to show my problem a bit more interactive.
I have an endpoint that returns a object containing a list of objects. I do not want to compare the actual values of my pact, I just want to match the type.
My Pact looks like this:
  @Pact(consumer = "Consumer", provider = "Provider")
  fun multi(builder: PactBuilder): V4Pact {
    return builder
        .expectsToReceiveHttpInteraction("multi") { httpBuilder ->
          httpBuilder
              .withRequest { httpRequestBuilder ->
                httpRequestBuilder
                    .path("/multi")
                    .method("GET")
              }
              .willRespondWith { httpResponseBuilder ->
                httpResponseBuilder
                    .status(200)
                    .body(PactDslJsonBody()
                        .`object`("myData", PactDslJsonBody()
                            .eachLike("myData", 2)
                            .stringType("foo", "foo")
                            .`object`("bar", PactDslJsonBody()
                                .stringType("bar", "bar")
                            )
                        )
                    )
              }
        }
        .toPact()

Unfortunately it actually matches not only the size of the example list, but also the value of the fields.
Both of which is not wanted.
As the single return works fine I assume it has something to do with the .eachLike("myData", 2).
Any idea what I am doing wrong and how I can change it to get my desired outcome?
I already tried to ask in the Pact Slack workspace, but unfortunately nobody could help me there :(

I still do not know what the problem with the current implementation is. But I can easier manage it when switching to the LambdaDsl:
.body(
  newJsonBody { o: LambdaDslJsonBody ->
    o.eachLike("myData", 2
        ) { d: LambdaDslObject ->
          d
              .stringType("foo", "foo")
              .`object`("bar") { bar: LambdaDslObject ->
                bar
                    .stringType("bar", "bar")
              }
        }
  }.build()
)


I think I see what's going on. When you use stringType("foo", "foo") in your Pact, you're telling Pact to expect the key "foo" with the specific value "foo" and match its type as a string so Pact matches both type and exact value.
To have Pact match only the type and not the specific value, you should omit the example value. So instead of:
.stringType("foo", "foo")

Just use:
.stringType("foo")

This way, Pact knows that "foo" should be a string, but it won't enforce any specific value during matching.
With your list make sure you're not specifying exact values you don't want to match. eachLike method can be used without specifying the number of examples unless you need to.
adjustements:
body(
    PactDslJsonBody()
        .`object`("myData",
            PactDslJsonBody()
                .eachLike("myData")
                    .stringType("foo") // No example value
                    .`object`("bar",
                        PactDslJsonBody()
                            .stringType("bar") // No example value
                    )
                .closeObject()
        )
)

removing specific example values, Pact will focus on matching types rather than the values. Hopefully this is the outcome you're looking for, where your tests only care about the structure and data types, not the actual content. lmk.

well but if I would care for the value in a pact I would use stringValue. For me the stringType(string, string) methods says basically "For the Pact, foo is a string, for the test, foo=foo". how else would you define a value for your test case?

Hope my edits helped :)

Hi, as mentioned in my comment unfortunately that is not what I am looking for. For the behaviour you are describing I would use stringValue which expects a specific value. In all other tests I am using exactly the same stringtype pattern and it works that for the test it is returning the values, BUT for the actual check on provider side it is only checking against the type. See for that also my single pact which works fine

here you can see the stringvalue signature, which describes exactly what you are explaining

And here you can see the signature for stringtype. it is only for example bodies. the other method you mention can be found here and actually uses the method I am using under the hood, only it generates its own examples
